# jQuery creating a draggable div and storing x,y positions to a text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that creates a `<div>` with a unique id each time, that `<div>` is also draggable via jQuery. The jQuery first appends a set of input boxes to a form outside of the main draggable area. then appends the draggable content its self to the container.

I am trying to use the drag event to store the x, y positions to the input boxes but I am having issues where the x,y positions are not returned to the text boxes within the form.

This is the code I am trying to get working:

```
<input type="button" name="AddDesk" id="AddDesk" value="Normal Desk" />
<div id="dContainer">
</div>
<form name="FormName" action="?cmd=function.save.layout" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="save" value="save" />
<div id="dataContainer">
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var i = 1;
$("#AddDesk").click(function() {
  $("<div />", { "class":"deskdata", id:"data"+i })
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posX"+i, style: "width:50px" }))
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posY"+i, style: "width:50px" }))
     .appendTo("#dataContainer");
});
$("#AddDesk").click(function() {
  $("<div />", { "class":"desk", id:"D"+i }).draggable({
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            $('#posX'+i).val('x:' + xPos);
            $('#posY'+i).val('y:' + yPos);
        }
    })
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"name"+i, style: "width:50px", value: "NAME" }))
     .appendTo("#dContainer");
  i++;
});
</script>
```

[jsfiddle version](http://jsfiddle.net/kaisummers/f83Vy/)

Comment: Define "issues", and please provide a jsfiddle version =)

Comment: As per your suggestion, I've edited the question to include the info you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to your call to "i" in your drag event. You cannot call "i" as it is an increment variable, you need to get the id of the dragged panel.

http://jsfiddle.net/TXp74/

```
var i = 1;
$("#AddDesk").click(function() {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $("<div />", { "class":"desk", id:"D"+i }).draggable({
        drag: function(){
            var offset = $(this).offset();
            var xPos = offset.left;
            var yPos = offset.top;
            console.log(xPos);
            $('#posX'+$(this).attr("id").replace('D','')).val('x:' + xPos);
            $('#posY'+$(this).attr("id").replace('D','')).val('y:' + yPos);
        }
    })
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"name"+i, style: "width:50px", value: "NAME" }))
     .appendTo("#dContainer");
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $("<div />", { "class":"deskdata", id:"data"+i })
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posX"+i, style: "width:50px" }))
     .append($("<input />", { type: "text", id:"posY"+i, style: "width:50px" }))
     .appendTo("#dataContainer");
     //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  i++;
});
```